# Untouchable Numbers

Tags: performance, haskell, mathematics, state

I wrote this program in response to a [CodeGolf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54239/31441) that required generating this sequence of "untouchable" numbers. This sequence can be found on OEIS as [A005114](https://oeis.org/A005114).

My initial implementation was prohibitively slow when asked for anything other than the first few terms so, I wrote this implementation with the goal of trading off memory usage for speed by maintaining an internal state representing already calculated values.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map as M
import System.Environment

main = do 
  n:_ <- getArgs
  print $ evalState (take (read n) <$> untouchables) M.empty

--A state monad containing a map from integers to the sum of their proper divisors
type CalcualtedSumsST = State (M.Map Int Int)  

--Generates an infinite list of untouchable numbers
untouchables :: CalcualtedSumsST [Int]
untouchables = filterM untouchable [1..]

--Tests weather a number is untouchable
untouchable :: Int -> CalcualtedSumsST Bool
untouchable 1 = return False
untouchable n = all (/=n) <$> mapM properDivisorSum [1..(n-1)*(n-1)]

--calculated the sum of the proper divisors of a number and adds it to the state
--or returns the pre-calculated if one is present
properDivisorSum :: Int -> CalcualtedSumsST Int
properDivisorSum n = do
  preCalulated <- get 
  if M.member n preCalulated then
    return $ preCalulated M.! n
  else do
    let dSum = sum $ properDivisors n
    put $ M.insert n dSum preCalulated
    return dSum

--generate a list of all the proper divisors of a number
properDivisors :: Int -> [Int]
properDivisors n = 1:(nub $ do
      --I think this is better than an equivalent list comprehension because 
      --it lets me utilize divMod instead of using div and mod separately
      x <- [2..floor.sqrt.fromIntegral $ n]
      let (q,r) = divMod n x
      if r==0 then [x,q] else [])
```

I'm primarily looking for review of my use of the `State` monad as this is an area of Haskell I have very little experience in. This code is still slower than I would like it, struggling to compute the first 50 terms of the sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The State monad

You are using the State monad to memoize the sum of the proper divisors calculation, and there is a pure way (i.e. not using a monad) of doing that.

The easiest way is to use the `Data.MemoCombinators` module to build a memoizing version of your function:

```
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo

divSum n = ...compute the sum of proper divisors of n...

memoDivSum = Memo.integral divSum

isTouchable n = any (\k -> memoDivSum k == n) [1..n*n]
```

The function `memoDivSum` works just like `divSum` except that it caches previously calculated values in a trie.

Update: In practice I've found that a better way to implement `isTouchable` is to iterate from `n*n` downwards.

#### A better algorithm

Note that your algorithm to find the untouchable numbers <= n is actually O(n^3). To determine if k is untouchable is O(k^2) and you're doing that for all the numbers k from 1 through n.

Here is a slightly better approach:

```
import Data.List

touchableList n = dedup $ sort $ filter (<= n) $ map divSum [1..n*n]
  where dedup [] = []
        dedup (x:xs) = x : dedup ( dropWhile (==x) xs )
```

It finds the touchable numbers, but they appear in sorted order, so finding the untouchable ones shouldn't be hard and is left as an exercise.

Note you don't need to memoize `divSum` now because you are only calling it once for each value of k, k from 1 through n*n.

#### Even faster

The fastest method I can think of gets away from pure functional programming and uses mutable arrays and sieves.

Comment: Thanks for the review! I didn't know there was a term for what I was doing let alone that it was already implemented in Haskell. I'll wait a day or so before accepting an answer to give more people time to post.

Comment: dedup is more simply written as `dedup = (map head) . group`